# How to make the application run several processes, each of which used a separate XML settings file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a conditional example.
There are:
 - files with settings (file "Likewise"):
 - .. \ 01 \ setting \ fold_1 \ settings_1.xml
..  \ 01 \ setting \  fold_2 \ settings_2.xml
.. \ 01 \ setting \ fold_3 \ settings_3.xml
 - data files (used for example (file "Data")):
.. \ 01 \ data \ fol_data_1 \ fol_data_1.txt
.. \ 01 \ data \ fol_data_2 \ fol_data_2.txt
.. \ 01 \ data \ fol_data_3 \ fol_data_3.txt

The "Settings" files are displayed in the tree view.
When you move the focus to the tree, all settings are displayed in the form fields depending on the file.
The number of settings in the example is conventionally accepted.
In fact, the example uses the "File data" setting "Data" (textBox4) ".
Those. in each "settings_N.xml" the path to the corresponding "Data" file.

Scenario.

1. The user. Selects one or more "Likewise" files in the tree;

   The choice is made by checking the CheckBox certificate to "true";

   2. The user. Click "Run" button (button3);
   3. The program. Creates a separate tab in the "tabControl" of each "Data" file; (in this example, "tabControl" is not used)
   4. The program. Creates tables DateTable for each file "Data";
   5. The program. Creates DateGrid for each "Data" file;
   6. The program. Parse data from the "Data" file;
   7. The program. Logs into DateTable;
   8. The program. Places in DataGrid;

Items 4 - 7 must be executed simultaneously for all selected "Nystroka" files.
In this example, the "Run" button (button3) executes the script for only one "Data" file.

I suspect this should be done by means of "multithreading" (Thread), but I can not figure out how to approach it.

Or are there other ways?

Question.

1. How to implement this scenario?
2. How to organize classes?

**Form1.cs**
Code - [link](https://codeshare.io/5MyVWW)

Project - [link](https://ufile.io/mleyw)

[Pic_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zB4P.png)
[Pic_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUqpz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would say use a BackgroundWorker ?!

Here is a link with a nice example, if needed I will provide a example myself.
[BackGroundWorkder Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners)

Edit:

This is a little example for you

```
private void MethodForWorker()
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    // This is where we create the event that will run on the background, not blocking the main thread
    worker.DoWork += this.Worker_DoWork;
    // This is where we create the event that will run after the backgroun as finished doing its work, this is not necessary per say, only if you need for it to run something after the background work is done
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += this.Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    // To start the background work
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // This is where you put the code that will run on the background
    // Remenber, to send stuff to the main thread you must use the invoke
    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        // Code of what you need to pass to the main thread, for example to use a MessageBox or to update a label ? up to you if you need to do stuff on the main thread
    }));
}

private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // This is where you put the code that will run after the Worker_DoWork has finnish doing all is job
}
```