# How to display multiple processes in one user control?

Tags: c#, winforms

A conditional example.
There are:
- data files (used for example (file "Data")):
.. \ 01 \ data \ fol_data_1 \ fol_data_1.txt
.. \ 01 \ data \ fol_data_2 \ fol_data_2.txt
.. \ 01 \ data \ fol_data_3 \ fol_data_3.txt
 
The "Data" files are displayed in the tree view.
The user can add, delete, modify the "Data" files.
 
Scenario.
1. The user. Selects one or more "Data" files (fol_data_ "N") in the tree;
The choice is made by means of translating CheckBoxes to "true";
2. The user. Click "Run" button (button3);
 
 
3. The program. Creates tables "DateTable" for each file "Data";
4. The program. Creates "DateGrid" for each "Data" file;
5. The program. Parse data from the "Data" file;
6. The program. He writes in "DateTable";
7. The program. Brings in "DataGrid";
  
Items 3 - 7 must be executed simultaneously for all selected "Data" files.
Items 3 - 7 are placed in the user control "GridUserControl".
While the program performs the process of transferring lines from the "Data" file to "DateTable", the user can navigate the tree with the cursor.
If the user enters the "Data" file for a process for which it is already running, then "panel3" displays "GridUserControl" with the current "DateGrid" filling state in rows/
 
Question.
1. How to implement this scenario?
2. What are the comments (proposals) for implementing this scenario?

PROJEKT - [LINK](https://ufile.io/wq8as)
[pic_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45a7q.png)

**GridUserControl.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeView_FolderTree
{
    public partial class GridUserControl : UserControl
    {

        public string pathFileData;

        public GridUserControl(string pathFileData)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Обрабатываем данные
            //Или записываем их в поле
            this.pathFileData = pathFileData;

        }

        private void GridUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            start_GridUserControl();
        }

        public void start_GridUserControl()
        {
            DataTable table_1;

            //привязка данных
            BindingSource bs;


            table_1 = new DataTable();
            table_1.Columns.Add("Content", typeof(string));
            table_1.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof(DateTime));

            bs = new BindingSource(table_1, "");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
            dataGridView1.Columns["DateTime"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss tt";



            // Читаем файл "Данные"
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathFileData);

            // System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteLines2.txt = ");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                //создаем новую запись
                DataRow newrow = table_1.NewRow();

                //заполняем ее данными
                newrow["Content"] = line;
                newrow["DateTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                //заносим запись в таблицу
                table_1.Rows.Add(newrow);

                //обновляем данные в гриде
                bs.ResetBindings(false);

                // Пауза
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                Application.DoEvents();

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker ?! And all rdy have seen this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964459/how-to-make-the-application-run-several-processes-each-of-which-used-a-separate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the application run several processes, each of which used a separate XML settings file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964459/how-to-make-the-application-run-several-processes-each-of-which-used-a-separate)

Answer (score 0):

Did so.

Am I on the right track or are there better ways?

*** Code Form1.cs ***
Creating TreeView

```
#region  *** TreeView Создание***
        private void InitFolders()
        {
            //Отключаем любую перерисовку
            //иерархического представления.
            treeView1.BeginUpdate();

            //Инициализируем новую переменную предоставляющую методы экземпляра
            //класса для создания, перемещения и перечисления
            //в каталогах и подкаталогах.
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di;
            try
            {
                //Вызываем метод GetDirectories с передачей в качестве параметра, пути к 
                //выбранной директории. Данный метод возвращает
                //массив имен подкаталогов.
                string[] root = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path);

                //Проходимся по всем полученным подкаталогам.
                foreach (string s in root)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Заносим в переменную информацию
                        //о текущей директории.
                        di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(s);
                        //Вызов метода сканирования с
                        //передачей в качестве параметра, информации
                        //о текущей директории и объект 
                        //System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection,
                        //который предоставляет узлы
                        //дерева, назначенные элементу управления 
                        //иерархического представления.
                        BuildTree(di, treeView1.Nodes);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
            catch { }
            //Разрешаем перерисовку иерархического представления.
            treeView1.EndUpdate();
        }       

        //Процесс получения папок и файлов
        private void BuildTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, TreeNodeCollection addInMe)
        {
            //Добавляем новый узел в коллекцию Nodes
            //с именем текущей директории и указанием ключа 
            //со значением "Folder".
            TreeNode curNode = addInMe.Add("Folder", directoryInfo.Name);

            //addInMe.Add(directoryInfo.FullName, directoryInfo.Name, 
            //тут можно указать номер картинки для узла из imageCollection);

            //Перебираем папки.
            foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo subdir in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                //Запускам процесс получения папок и файлов 
                //с текущей найденной директории.
                BuildTree(subdir, curNode.Nodes);
            }

            //Перебираем файлы
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                //Добавляем новый узел в коллекцию Nodes
                //С именем текущей директории и указанием ключа 
                //со значением "File".
                curNode.Nodes.Add("File", file.Name);

                //curNode.Nodes.Add("File", file.Name, 
                //тут можно указать номер картинки для узла из imageCollection);  
            }
        }
        #endregion *** TreeView ***
```

"Run" button

```
 // Выполнить 
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            // Перебор выбранных узлов "treeView"
               TreeNodeCollection Nodes;
               Nodes = treeView1.Nodes;

               CheckTrueTreeNode(Nodes);
        }
```

Recruiting. treeview. CheckTrueTreeNode (TreeNodeCollection Nodes)

```
#region *** Рекруссия. treeView ***
        void CheckTrueTreeNode(TreeNodeCollection Nodes)
        {
                foreach (TreeNode tn in Nodes)
                {
                    if (tn.Checked == true)
                    {
                    // textBox1.Text += (tn.Name + " -**//**- " + path + tn.FullPath + "\r\n");  // инфо сообщение 
                    //treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
                    //treeView1.SelectedNode = tn;
                    //tn.EnsureVisible();
                    //return;

                    // путь к выбранному файлу 
                    pathFileData = path + tn.FullPath;

                    // BackgroundWorker. Старт
                    bw_start();

                    }

                    CheckTrueTreeNode(tn.Nodes);
                }
        }
        #endregion *** Рекруссия ***
```

Start "BackgroundWorker". bw_start ()

```
private void bw_start()
         {
                // bw = new BackgroundWorker[];                
                i++;

                //новый поток
                bw[i] = new BackgroundWorker();
                bw[i].WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                bw[i].WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

                bw[i].DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork); 
                bw[i].RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted); //обработчик 
                bw[i].ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);

                if (bw[i].IsBusy != true)
                bw[i].RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                DataTable table_1;

                //привязка данных
                BindingSource bs;


                table_1 = new DataTable();
                table_1.Columns.Add("Content", typeof(string));
                table_1.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof(DateTime));

                bs = new BindingSource(table_1, "");


                // Читаем файл "Данные"
                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathFileData);

                // System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteLines2.txt = ");
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    // создаем новую запись
                    DataRow newrow = table_1.NewRow();

                    // заполняем ее данными
                    newrow["Content"] = line;
                    newrow["DateTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                    // заносим запись в таблицу
                    table_1.Rows.Add(newrow);

                    // обновляем данные в грид
                    bs.ResetBindings(false);

                    // Пауза
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }

        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {

            }

        static void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {

            }
```

Paragraph:
"While the program is executing the process of moving lines from the" Data "file to" DateTable ", the user can navigate the tree with the cursor.
If the user enters the "Data" file for a process that has already been started, "GridUserControl" is displayed in "panel3" with the current state of filling "DateGrid" with "

```
Provides 
// События TreeView/ Происходит после выбора узла дерева.
        private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(Object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();

            GridUserControl GridUsCont = new GridUserControl(????);

            panel1.Controls.Add(GridUsCont);

        }
```

*** GridUserControl.cs ***

```
namespace TreeView_FolderTree
{
    public partial class GridUserControl : UserControl
    {

        public string pathFileData;

        public GridUserControl(string pathFileData)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Обрабатываем данные
            //Или записываем их в поле
* *         this.pathFileData = pathFileData;

        }

        private void GridUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            start_GridUserControl();
        }

        public void start_GridUserControl()
        {            
            // dataGridView1
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
            dataGridView1.Columns["DateTime"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss tt";            

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: @Camadas Could you see if I'm on the right track?
And if it is not difficult for you to give advice how to do it correctly?